# How prove this $x^3<\sin^2{x}\tan{x},x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: inequality

show that

> $$x^3<\sin^2{x}\tan{x},x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ have nice methods? Thank you

my try:
$$\Longleftrightarrow \cos{x}\cdot x^3<(\sin{x})^3$$

let
$$f(x)=\cos{x}\cdot x^3-(\sin{x})^3$$
$$\Longrightarrow f'(x)=-\sin{x}\cdot x^3+3\cos{x}\cdot x^2-3(\sin{x})^2\cos{x}$$

Comment: I think that direct methods will serve better than using derivatives...  Also, make sure to point out whether $\cos x\gt 0$ over the given interval...

Comment: The inequality cannot be right because the right-hand side goes to $\infty$
as $x \rightarrow \pi/2$.  The reverse inequality 
$x^3 < \sin^2 x \tan x$ does hold on $0 < x < \pi/2$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you,@NoamD.Elkies,I have edit

Comment: Duplicate / similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127021/show-fx-x3-sin2x-tanx-0-on-0-frac-pi2, which uses power series expansions.

Comment: @CalvinLin O, thanks. Both of the solutions are more complex than the one I gave here. I would like just to add that this problem is one of the examples of not exactly fair entrance exams in the former Soviet Union ([more on this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1556)). In particular, this problem was asked in the oral exam.

Comment: @Artem Haha, yes, I've heard about the "Jewish problems".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider an equivalent inequality
   $$
   \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt[3]{\cos x}}>x.
   $$
2. It is enough to show that the derivative of the left-hand side is bigger than the derivative of the right hand side. After some simplification this should be (if I did not make any mistakes)
   $$
   2 \cos ^2 x+1-3\cos ^{4/3} x>0
   $$
3. Using $u=\cos^2 x$ you get 
   $$
   2u+1>3u^{2/3},\quad 0<u<1.
   $$
   The last inequality is true because $3u^{2/3}$ is increasing, concave, and the derivative at 1 is equal to 2 (make a graph).

Comment: Interesting that OP said +1, but I don't see it appear. Here's a +1 from me.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin^3x-x^3 \cos x=\frac14\left(3\sin x-\sin(3x)\right)-x^3 \cos x\ge0 \iff 3\sin x-\sin(3x)-4x^3\cos x \ge 0$$

and since by Taylor's series

- $\sin x\ge x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5-\frac1{5040}x^7$
- $\sin (3 x)\le 3x-\frac 9 2 x^3+\frac{81}{40}x^5-\frac{243}{560}x^7+\frac{243}{4480}x^9$
- $\cos x\le 1-\frac12 x^2+\frac1{24}x^4$

then

$$ 3\sin x-\sin(3x)-4x^3\cos x\ge $$

$$\ge 3x-\frac12x^3+\frac1{40}x^5-\frac1{1680}x^7-3x+\frac 9 2 x^3-\frac{81}{40}x^5+\frac{243}{560}x^7-\frac{243}{4480}x^9-4x^3+2x^5-\frac1{6}x^8=$$

$$=-\frac1{1680}x^7+\frac{243}{560}x^7-\frac{243}{4480}x^9-\frac1{6}x^8=$$

$$=\frac{13}{30}x^7-\frac16 x^8-\frac{243}{4480}x^9\ge 0 \iff 729x^2+2240x-5824\le 0$$

which leads to $0\le x\le a\approx 1.68$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, by [Holder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), we have
$$\frac{\tan x}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}
=\int_{0}^{1}\sec^2(xt)\,\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\cos(xt)\,\mathrm{d}t
\int_{0}^{1}\cos(xt)\,\mathrm{d}t>\left(\int_{0}^{1}1\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^3
=1.$$
This implies
$$x^3<\sin^2{x}\tan{x},\quad x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right).$$